# How to configure DNS for Azure Private Endpoint in virtual network that uses Azure AD Domain Services

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I've set up an Azure virtual machine in a virtual network, and have joined it to an Azure AD Domain Services domain. The virtual network uses the AADDS DNS servers.

I've created a private link to connect to an Azure storage account file service in the virtual network, and I can confirm that it has an IP address in the subnet to which the virtual machine is connected.

However, from the virtual machine, the FQDN of the file share, storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net still resolves to the public IP address. This makes sense to me because there's no DNS record in the AADDS server for the private link. How do I configure the DNS so that the VM connects to the file service through the private link?

Edit: DNS won't even resolve to the private endpoint IP address if I add a record to the hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Because the AAD DS servers are being used as your primary DNS, you need to do one of the following:

- Configure zones for privatelink.blob.core.windows.net in your AAD DS DNS and add records for your Private Link resources
- Add a forwarder in your AAD DS DNS to forward requests for privatelink.blob.core.windows.net to an Azure Private DNS zone that you have linked to the network